# swift4 Decodable method correct structure to parse array buried inside JSON?

Tags: json, swift, swift4, decodable

Using SWIFT4 and Decodable I am trying to parse the first result from the array `pageids` at this [JSON URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts%7Cpageimages&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=rose&indexpageids=&redirects=1&pithumbsize=500), see [JSON IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRNd3.jpg) with the following code but I get nil value everytime; the issue seems to be with the fact that I can't assign any variable to represent pageids[0], any suggestion ? I also tried to nest the structures exactly like the JSON without any success either. I don't get it, every tutorial I find seem to do what I do...

```
struct WikiData: Decodable {
var batchcomplete: String
var query: [Query]
var pageids : [Pageids]
}
struct Query : Decodable {
    var pageids : [Pageids]
}
struct Pageids : Decodable {            
}

let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let datastring = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
print (datastring as Any) // JSON prints fine in console

let id = try? JSONDecoder().decode(WikiData.self, from: jsonData)
        print(WikiData?.pageids as Any)
```

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to be related to the decoding process moreover you are ignoring a potential error of `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: @vadian ok I removed it from the question

Comment: You are still ignoring the error which could give you a hint what's going on.

Comment: @vadian the decoder does not throw any error if that is what you mean ? if I try to parse `batchcomplete` it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to model your data right.

```
import Foundation

struct WikiData: Codable {
    var batchcomplete: String
    var query: Query
}

struct Query: Codable {
    var normalized: [[String: String]]
    var pageids: [String]
    var pages: [Int: PageData]
}

struct PageData: Codable {
    var pageid: Int
    var ns: Int
    var title: String
    var extract: String
    var thumbnail: Thumbnail
    var pageimage: String
}

struct Thumbnail: Codable {
    var source: URL
    var width: Int
    var height: Int
}

let url = URL(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts%7Cpageimages&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=rose&indexpageids=&redirects=1&pithumbsize=500")!
let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let datastring = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    // Decode data to object
    let object = try decoder.decode(WikiData.self, from: jsonData)
    print(object.query.pageids[0])
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```